# What is $data in _view.php of blog (demos folder) of yii framework is?

Tags: php, yii

I confuse about $data in blog/views/post/_view.php of blog demo of yii framework
How I get this attribute of $data? Where I can find the define of $data? I find in source but doesn't see any line about **author->username** ,url commentCount?

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="title">
        <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->title), $data->url); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="author">
        posted by <?php echo $data->author->username . ' on ' . date('F j, Y',$data->create_time); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <?php
            $this->beginWidget('CMarkdown', array('purifyOutput'=>true));
            echo $data->content;
            $this->endWidget();
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <b>Tags:</b>
        <?php echo implode(', ', $data->tagLinks); ?>
        <br/>
        <?php echo CHtml::link('Permalink', $data->url); ?> |
        <?php echo CHtml::link("Comments ({$data->commentCount})",$data->url.'#comments'); ?> |
        Last updated on <?php echo date('F j, Y',$data->update_time); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me to explain or give me some link or some keywork.
Thank for everything!

Answer (score 3):

See documentation for [`CListView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView):

> The above code first creates a data provider for the Post ActiveRecord
>   class. It then uses CListView to display every data item as returned
>   by the data provider. The display is done via the partial view named
>   '_post'. This partial view will be rendered once for every data item.
>   **In the view, one can access the current data item via variable $data.**
>   For more details, see itemView.

So in your context, `$data` is the Post being rendered.

Comment: but in the model of Post or PostController I dont see attributes: author->username, url ....

Comment: @chanhle: Yii automatically reads the DB schema associated with each Active Record class and creates magic attributes for every column. Table relations specified in the `relations()` function will also be available as magic attributes, but be careful about lazy loading. So `$data->url` refers to the value of that post's `url` field in the database, and `$data->author->username` will fetch the `author` of the post and return its `username` field. Check out http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr .

Comment: What about `$data->tagLinks` ? where does that come from?

Comment: @Samson: that involves a little bit of magic. In Yii, when you say `$data->tagLinks` and `$data` does not have a property named `tagLinks`, it will try to call `$data->getTagLinks()` instead. That is exactly what happens here, the `Post` model contains a function `getTagLinks()` that gets called.

Answer (score 2):

$data is an object of model class having single row of data.
author is a relation to another model of the model whose instance is $data.
$data->author->username Here username is a variable of the model whom author points.
$data->author also treated as an object. It will just execute a relational query to the model whom author points.

You can see the relations of the model in relations() function of the model.
Try out guide of yii you will find your answer.

Comment: relation is this here
public function relations()
 {
  // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
  // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
  return array(
   'author' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'author_id'),
   'comments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'post_id', 'condition'=>'comments.status='.Comment::STATUS_APPROVED, 'order'=>'comments.create_time DESC'),
   'commentCount' => array(self::STAT, 'Comment', 'post_id', 'condition'=>'status='.Comment::STATUS_APPROVED),
  );
 }